# psycopg2 DB Exception: UnicodeError

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

DatabaseErrors in django with psycopg2 are sometimes non-ascii byte strings:

```
DatabaseError('FEHLER:  Wert zu lang f\xc3\xbcr Typ character varying(10)\n',)
```

This results in UnicodeErrors.....

All other unicode handling works fine. Any chance to get the error message from psycopg2 as unicode string?

Version: python-psycopg2-2.4.4-2.1.x86_64